Representation of fixed point numbers
I want to understand what is the representation of numbers in binary format, in which the maximum number is 1 and in binary format (with a width of 8 bits) this is 0_1111111. The minimum number is -1 and in binary it is 1_0000000.
It is clear that the highest bit is the sign of a number, and 7 ones means that the number 1 is the maximum, and 7 zeros means that -1 is the minimum.
Most likely, this is a normalized floating-point representation, but I can't adapt the numbers according to the normalization rules.How, for example, should I represent the number 0.02 in this case? Thanks.

You have not provided as much information as you should. One possibility is the number x is represented with the two’s complement binary numeral for (255x−1)/2. (So, for x = 1, (255x−1)/2 is 127, and the binary numeral is 01111111, and for x = −1, (255•−1−1)/2 = −128, and the binary numeral is 10000000.) Another is you are incorrect about 0_1111111 representing 1; it actually represents 127/128, and the number x is represented with the two’s complement binary numeral for 128x. Both of these are fixed-point representations, not floating-point.

You should edit the question to add context about where this comes from.

@den251 Can you post a few more example values and their bit patterns?  It would be useful to have, say, 1/2 and -1/2, and 1/4 and -1/4, and 3/4 and -3/4, and maybe a few ±x/8 values, too.

sounds good to me, shall we delete the followup comments, too?

@SteveSummit I'm sorry, but I don't know practically anything about this, except what is written in the question. But I think  Eric Postpischi right, this does not apply to floating point.

@den251 Thanks for replying, but yes, it sounds like we don't have quite enough information here.  It seems likely that the fractional range -1..1 is being mapped linearly onto the binary range 100000000..0..01111111, meaning that +½ would be 00111111 or 01000000, and 0.2 would be 00011010.  (This is more or less what Eric was saying in his first comment). To be more precise we'd need to know whether the 8-bit number is actually being thought of as two's complement or something else, and whether 01111111 actually corresponds to 1.0, or to 127/128 = 0.9921875.

The requirements stated in the post do not match any common format. Here are three of the least unlikely possibilities.
Linear: A number x is represented with the eight-bit two‘s complement numeral for ½(255x−1):

x = 1 ➝ ½(255•1 − 1) = 127 ➝ 0111 1111.
x = −1 ➝ ½(255•−1 − 1) = −128 ➝ 1000 0000.

Issues with this include: Zero is not representable. (x = 0 ➝ ½(255•0 − 1) = −½.) Linear representations with a non-zero offset are rarely used as a general format. One might be used as a specialized solution for a particular problem.
One’s complement fixed-point: A number x is represented with the eight-bit one’s complement numeral for 127x:

x = 1 ➝ 127•1 = 127 ➝ 0111 1111.
x = −1 ➝ 127•−1 = −127 ➝ 1000 0000.

In other words, the point is fixed after the first bit and before the last seven bits.
An issue with this is that one’s complement is rarely used. This might be encountered in an academic exercise but rarely in modern practice.
Incorrect specification: A number x is represented with the eight-bit two’s complement numeral for 128x, and the post was incorrect to state that 0111 1111 represents 1. Instead, it represents 127/128, a number near one.
Obviously, an issue with this is it contradicts the post. However, “off by one” errors occur commonly in computing, and it is not uncommon to encounter situations where we want to span some aesthetic interval like [−1, 1] but there are boundary issues. Were it not for this issue, this would be a clean solution.
In any case, there are no signs this is a floating-point format.
.2 does not have an exact representation in any of the formats above; rounding would be necessary.
